# Using LINQ to XML to create a pair of XElement on the same level for each Object in a List of Object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to build an XML document that should output, for each object `Journey` in the list `List<Journey> journeys` :

```
<Journeys>
    <id>1</id>
    <length>28</length>
    <id>2</id>
    <length>44</length>
    etc.
</Journeys>
```

I've tried to use LINQ to XML with the following code :

```
var journeyElement = new XElement("Journeys",
    journeys.Select(j => 
        new XElement("id", j.id),
        new XElement("length", j.length));
```

Which is apparently not the expected syntax.

```
var journeyElement = new XElement("Journey",
    journeys.Select(j => new
    {
        id = new XElement("id", j.id),
        length = new XElement("length", j.length)
    }));
```

Which doesn't produce the expected result.

How would one proceed to create a pair of `XElement` on the same level from a `List` using LINQ to XML ?

Comment: The structure of your XML is not clear. I assume that the "root" is called `Journeys` and that it has `Journey` elements. Your XML example lists `Journeys` as element and the C# code has both versions. Please revise the examples so that we can better understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can project each `Journey` into an array of two elements then flatten them into a single list with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
var journeyElement = new XElement("Journeys", 
    journeys.SelectMany(j => new[] { new XElement("id", j.id), new XElement("length", j.length) }));
```

This produces the desired XML:

> ```
> <Journeys>
>   <id>1</id>
>   <length>28</length>
>   <id>2</id>
>   <length>44</length>
> </Journeys>
> ```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

If you can change the XML structure like this,

```
<Journeys>
    <Journey>
        <id>1</id>
        <length>28</length>
    </Journey>
    <Journey>
        <id>2</id>
        <length>44</length>
    </Journey>
    etc.
</Journeys>
```

This code will work.

```
List<Journey> journeys;

var journeyElement = new XElement("Journeys",
                            journeys.Select(j =>
                                new XElement("Journey",
                                    new XElement("id", j.id),
                                    new XElement("length", j.length)
                                    )
                                )
                            );
```